# fire click event for button

Tags: grid, extjs

I have column with buttons like this:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
               store: store,
               columns: [
               {
                   header: 'Issue',
                   renderer: function(val){ 
                       return '<input type="button" class="btnissue" value="Issue" />';
                   }, 
                   dataIndex: 'btn', width: 49 
               }
            ],
            renderTo: Ext.get('Issuing')
        });
```

And I want to fire click events for this buttons.
If I write :

```
   Ext.getCmp('btnissue').on('click',function(){
        alert("message");
   });
```

It says that the button does not exist.
So how can I fire this event?

Answer (score 2):

[`getCmp`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext-method-getCmp) looks up an ExtJS component. As YOU create the button you should use [`get`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext-method-get) instead.

Comment: Are you sure render event is fired before you define yours?

Comment: maybe it bind the event before the button be create.How I can check it or fix it without check...

Comment: I think you have to define click event in your grid **render** or **afterrender** event to make sure buttons exist.